# Not able to connect to HTTPS service using ISTIO Gateway and Virtual Service

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, istio

As I am new to istio, along with all my team members, we would really appreciate if we can get some help here.

**Problem**
I have followed the below documentation to create certs and create secrets in k8s using the application cert and key
https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/#troubleshooting

After that I restarted my istio-ingressgateway pod so that it loads the certs. Which aanyway I can see inside the pod when I exec.

And I have added below annotation in istio-ingressgateway service to use domain names:
*external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: *.byom-i344382.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com*

**My virtualService and Gateway resources looks like this which are residing in 'default' namespace:**

```
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: ms-is-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "ms-1234.byom-i344382.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ms-is
spec:
  hosts:
  - "ms-1234.byom-i344382.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com"
  gateways:
  - ms-is-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /api/v2/predict
    route:
    - destination:
        host: mlf-is
        port:
          number: 53547
```

> Note that mlf-is service is in default namespace too. Only the istio-ingressgateway is in the istio-system namespace

**Expected behavior**
When I hit https://ms-1234.byom-i344382.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com/api/v2/predict from POSTMAN I should be able to reach ms-is service. However, I am not able to reach the service.

even the below curl command is failing:
curl -v --cacert /home/vagrant/exmaple/mtls-go-example/2_intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem https://ms-1234.byom-i344382.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com:443/api/v2/predict

Error from curl:

  `Trying 18.195.217.210...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ms-1234.byom-i344382.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com (18.195.217.210) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/vagrant/exmaple/mtls-go-example/2_intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to ms-1234.byom-i344382.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to ms-1234.byom-i344382.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com:443`

**Version**
Version of istio: 1.0.1 and Kubernetes: 1.0.9

**Is Istio Auth enabled or not?**
Installed istio.yaml

**Environment**
Cloud vendor is AWS

Comment: What is the protocol on the 53547 port of `mlf-is`? Can you connect to it from inside the cluster?

Comment: @VadimEisenberg http, yes able to access from inside the cluster. 
I added port 80 in my gateway resource with httpsRedirect set to true and my requests started passing. 
Many people seems to be facing that issue : https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6071