# Unable to setup https in Istio Gateway

Tags: https, gateway, istio

Setting up Istio Gateway using http is fine.

But I can't set up https. I followed the guide https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/

Istio: 1.0.2 (Install using Helm)
Kubernetes 1.10.3 eks

I am using COMODO's certificate.

Only first time, I can access the page using https. 
After accessing page, if I try to connect again, I am getting the following error in browser.

```
mycompany.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
```

If I am using curl, I am getting the following error.

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to qa-web.ffau.to:443
```

If I am testing using openssl,

openssl s_client -tls1 -connect mycompany.com:443 -msg

The error

```
140735917949896:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:522:
```

This is how I created secret.

```
kubectl create -n istio-system secret tls istio-ingressgateway-certs --key ffau.to.key  --cert ffau.to.crt
```

This is yaml of gateway and virtual service.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mycompany-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
servers:
 - port:
     number: 443
     name: https
     protocol: HTTPS
   tls:
     mode: SIMPLE
     serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
     privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
   - "mycompany.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ffau-qa-phoenix-us
spec:
  hosts:
  - "mycompany.com"
  gateways:
  - mycompany-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
       prefix: /us/account
    - uri:
        prefix: /us/reserve
    - uri:
        exact: /phoenix-bundle.js
    - uri:
       exact: /client-env.js
    - uri:
       exact: /env-variables
    - uri:
       exact: /graphql
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myui.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8000
```

Answer (score 5):

There was a similar issue in stack-overflow 
[Not able to connect to HTTPS service using ISTIO Gateway and Virtual Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147459/not-able-to-connect-to-https-service-using-istio-gateway-and-virtual-service), https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6071

I found a workaround in [stack-overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147459/not-able-to-connect-to-https-service-using-istio-gateway-and-virtual-service). Opening port 80 and redirect to 443 using httpsRedirect: true

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec :
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
 - port:
     number: 80
     name: http
     protocol: HTTP
   hosts:
   - "mydomain.com"
   tls:
     httpsRedirect: true
 - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "mydomain.com"
```